# Jquery UI formatting not working on external server

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am trying to get the DatePicker widget from jquery UI to render nicely on both the local and QA server. It formats fine on the local machine but not on the QA machine.

When I compare the source code of the specific page of the DatePicker widget between the local and QA server, they are identical. The browser, browser version and computer I am using to access the page are identical. Could there be some server configuration that is causing the DatePicker widget to be incorrectly formatted?

Comment: have you checked if the libraries are loading right?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the css files are loading right?.. I had this issue recently, when the css files weren't loading right or images were missing, because I wanted to use a local version of the css file. (I'm talking about the jquery ui css file here)

Comment: Do you mean that css files could have an absolute path instead of a relative path?

Comment: Upon using Chrome Developer tools, it seems as both local and QA server are attempting to load the same 3 min.map files and are unsuccessful.

Comment: @Gengar : I would use an absolute path whenever possible, to avoid issues that may come up with calling css files or the images that are called inside the css files.
Are the files on your server? If so, have you tried to use the jquery ui files from the original server?